# "name does not exist in the current context" error

Tags: c#

I am coding a rcon message tool for a game server in C#. However I've run across a error:

> "The name 'm' does not exist in the current context"

By now you're shouting at your screen NOOB! and yes I admit I am; I have little real coding experience.

I've played with MFC C++ and OpenGL and I'm a fairly respected cod modder "script is gsc loosely based on c++" so I hope I can learn quickly, basically I tried to access an instance of b. outside of the main loop but it gave me the error:

> The name b does not exist in the current context

so I made a new messages function that started a new connection in a new instance. Then I tried the access that in another function `stopmessages()` but I still get the error.

Sorry for the newb question. I've googled long and hard about this and I just don't understand.

Here's my code - it uses `Nini.dll` for config file access and `BattleNET.dll` for access to rcon for the game -

```
#region

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using BattleNET;
using Nini.Config;
#endregion



namespace BattleNET_client
{

internal class Program
{
    
   private static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isit_ok = true;
        
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.Title = "rotceh_dnih's DayZ servermessages";
        BattlEyeLoginCredentials loginCredentials = GetLoginCredentials();
        Console.Title += string.Format(" - {0}:{1}", loginCredentials.Host, loginCredentials.Port);
        IBattleNET b = new BattlEyeClient(loginCredentials);
        b.MessageReceivedEvent += DumpMessage;
        b.DisconnectEvent += Disconnected;
        b.ReconnectOnPacketLoss(true);
        b.Connect();
        
        while (true)
        {
            startmessages();
            string cmd = Console.ReadLine();

            if (cmd == "exit" || cmd == "logout" || cmd == "quit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            if (cmd == "restart")
            {
                stopmessages();
            }
            if (cmd == "startstuff")
            {
                startmessages();
            }

            if (b.IsConnected())
            {
                if (isit_ok)
                {
                    
                }
                isit_ok = false;
                b.SendCommandPacket(cmd);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not connected!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static BattlEyeLoginCredentials GetLoginCredentials()
    {
       
        IConfigSource source = new IniConfigSource("server/admindets.ini");
        string serverip = source.Configs["rconlogin"].Get("ip");
        int serverport = source.Configs["rconlogin"].GetInt("port");
        string password = source.Configs["rconlogin"].Get("rconpwd");
        var loginCredentials = new BattlEyeLoginCredentials
                                   {
                                       Host = serverip,
                                       Port = serverport,
                                       Password = password,
                                   };          
        return loginCredentials;
    }

   public static void startmessages()
    {
       BattlEyeLoginCredentials loginCredentials = GetLoginCredentials();
        IBattleNET m = new BattlEyeClient(loginCredentials);
        m.MessageReceivedEvent += DumpMessage;
        m.DisconnectEvent += Disconnected;
        m.ReconnectOnPacketLoss(true);
        m.Connect();

        IConfigSource messagesource = new IniConfigSource("messages/servermessages.ini");

        int messagewait = messagesource.Configs["timesettings"].GetInt("delay");
        string[] messages = messagesource.Configs["rconmessages"].Get("messages1").Split('|');
    //    for (;;)
      //  {
      
            foreach (string message in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                 m.SendCommandPacket(EBattlEyeCommand.Say,message);
                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(messagewait * 60 * 1000); 
                
            }
     //   }
       
    }


   public static void stopmessages()
   {
       
       m.Disconnect();
   }


    private static void Disconnected(BattlEyeDisconnectEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }

    private static void DumpMessage(BattlEyeMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the declaration of `m` into the class scope:

```
internal class Program
{

    // declare m as field at class level
    private static IBattleNET m;

    private static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ....
    }


    public static void startmessages()
    {
       BattlEyeLoginCredentials loginCredentials = GetLoginCredentials();


        // JUST SET THE VALUE HERE
        m = new BattlEyeClient(loginCredentials);
        m.MessageReceivedEvent += DumpMessage;
        m.DisconnectEvent += Disconnected;
        m.ReconnectOnPacketLoss(true);
        m.Connect();

        IConfigSource messagesource = new IniConfigSource("messages/servermessages.ini");

        int messagewait = messagesource.Configs["timesettings"].GetInt("delay");
        string[] messages = messagesource.Configs["rconmessages"].Get("messages1").Split('|');
    //    for (;;)
      //  {

            foreach (string message in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                 m.SendCommandPacket(EBattlEyeCommand.Say,message);
                 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(messagewait * 60 * 1000); 

            }
     //   }

    }
```

Comment: thank you very much it now works and i can get rid of the 2'nd instance that wanst really needed :)

Answer (score 1):

The stopmessages() method won't be able to access m as the variable m only exists within the startmessages() method

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of `IBattleNET m`

To outside the `main` function and make it static:

```
static IBattleNet b;
```

Then in your `main` you just do `m = new BattlEyeClient(loginCredentials);`

Answer (score 0):

`m` is declared in scope of static method `startmessages` but then you are trying to use it in `stopmessages`, where it is not in scope. You should move the variable to class scope, and define it as static (since your methods are static).

Hopefully your client app is single-threaded, otherwise you will need to consider thread safety issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is after you declared your class, so bevore the static void main
declare your m value

```
internal class Program
{
    IBattleNET m;
```

then in the startMessages method add

```
m = new BattlEyeClient(loginCredentials);
```

this will make the m value available to all the methods inside your class

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming m should refer to this:

```
IBattleNET m = new BattlEyeClient(loginCredentials);
```

in the method `startmessages()`. What you need to do is declare IBattleNET m outside the method body:

```
static IBattleNET m;
public static void startmessages()
{
    //etc
```